# How to add Application not website on IIS 7.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis-7.5

I am trying to add a new Application on IIS 7.5, but that option is not there!

[image]

any suggestions , am I missing something, or do I have to reinstall the IIS ?

tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the website as the parent entity and the application as a child.

You will need to add/create a website then you can add applications beneath the website.

I attempted to add some screen shots for you but apparently my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @BossRoss you need to right click on any website in IIS under sites and clik on Add Application here is the screenshot

[image]